# Working Kivy codes in Windows but blank screen on linux environment

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to do some cross platform testing. Here is a working code for Windows:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MatrixCalcLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return MatrixCalcLayout()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3App().run()
```

ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import kivy kivy

<MatrixCalcLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
```

When I try to run it on Ubuntu, it does load up and show the kivy canvas, but it's just a blank (black) screen as if it doesn't link to the .kv file.

Edited: Corrected the .kv file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [kivy docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html):

> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:

You could change the .kv file to `confusionmatrixcalc_v3.kv` or provide it explicitly when calling `run()`

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3App(kv_file="ConfusionMatrixCalc.kv").run()
```

Comment: Thanks, my apology, the kv file name is indeed ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3, my original post's naming was a typo. And it still doesn't work on linux.

Comment: I am using linux, and changing the .kv file to `confusionmatrixcalc_v3.kv` (note that it's all lowercase) is working. Is the .kv file in the same folder as the .py file? Also, how are you running your script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to eiter load the kv file with Builder:

```
Builder.load_file("ConfusionMatrixCalc.kv")
```

Or change your App class name from `ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3App` to `ConfusionMatrixCalcApp`

Comment: My apology, my .kv file name is actually "ConfusionMatrixCalc_v3.kv", I have corrected the naming from original post. And the issue remains, it works in Windows and doesn't work for Linux.

Comment: I have also tried your load_file method before, while it does make it work on Linux, it breaks after I compile it using buildozer into .apk. That's why I am trying to do it without the load_file method.